# Trying to install Wireless Archer T4U Driver

Tags: wireless, drivers, make

Attempting to install the TP-Link Archer T4U Driver. Downloaded files from https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4U

Have installed `build-essentials`.

```
$ sudo make clean

cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal/OUTSRC/ ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko 
cd hal/led ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*/*.mod.c */*/*.mod */*/*.o */*/.*.cmd */*/*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr */*.mod.c */*.mod */*.o */.*.cmd */*.ko
cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko
rm -fr Module.symvers ; rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod *.o .*.cmd *.ko *~
rm -fr .tmp_versions

$ sudo make

make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build M=/media/yolande/USB20FD/Wireless Driver/Attempt 1/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Driver/Attempt'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2


$ sudo make install    
install -p -m 644 8812au.ko  /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat ‘8812au.ko’: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
$
```

Comment: I am considering buying this device and I was wondering if you were able to make it work. If so why haven't you selected a correct answer? I really want to know about your experience with the usb adapter.

Answer (score 5):

I just did the following (on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) which worked. 
Make sure you have a working internet connection. Unplug the T4-U.
In a terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/
make
sudo make install
```

If you the plug in the T4-U (no restart or log out needed), it is recognised.

(Answer based on this article: http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=TPLINK_Archer_T4U_RTL8812au_Linux_Drivers, which is slightly outdated since there's no need to manually add the T4-U ID anymore).

Comment: It works, although you might want to have a look at the bundled README.md to setup DKMS so that the module gets rebuilt automatically every time your kernel is updated.

Comment: thanks a ton for this, I was in line with customer support for many hours and they could not solve it . Luckily found this link before returning it.

Answer (score 4):

'make' has trouble with path names with unescaped spaces in the names. I suggest you rename:

```
USB20FD/Wireless Driver/Attempt 1/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
```

To:

```
USB20FD/Wireless_Driver/Attempt_1/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux-master
```

And then try again.

Comment: I had this problem as well, and renaming spaces out of the parent directories fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have TP-Link Archer T4U and found the best solution here
[WiFi module 8812AU not working with kernel version >= 4.4.0-28-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832329/wifi-module-8812au-not-working-with-kernel-version-4-4-0-28-generic)

> `sudo -H gedit /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/dkms.conf`
>
> Then change line 4 from `MAKE="'make' all"` to `MAKE="'make' all
>   KVER=${kernelver}"`
>
> Save and exit the editor then do the same with:
>
> `sudo -H gedit /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/build/dkms.conf`
>
> As a similar problem was reported on Ubuntu Forums and my edits have
>   worked for the last kernel update I got.
>
> For your current kernel you should be able to:
>
> ```
> dkms build rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg -k 4.4.0-38-generic
> dkms install rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg -k 4.4.0-38-generic
> ```
>
> Reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the latest (4.8.1) kernel now and experience issues with other drivers, please feel free to try mine: https://github.com/Grief/archer-t4u It can also work on older kernels but I cannot guarantee