# Having problems seeing my wifi Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, bluetooth

Hello I having having issues seeing my wifi I bought my computer built from newegg and recently switched to Ubuntu it picks up my wired connection fine but doesn't even give my any options for my wifi dongle

would be grateful for some help if possible and thank you I have been trying to get it to work for days

I am not sure what type of device it is is says ac600 on the dongle which i look up and says it could be netgear or edimax

```
"lshw -C"
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: 74:d4:35:b8:50:ac
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:28 ioport:ce00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff


"lsusb"
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 154b:fa05 PNY Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1130:1620 Tenx Technology, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 004: ID a012:b012  
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 046d:0829 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

"ifconfig"
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:b8:50:ac  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: ::355f:6ae4:a42a:7481/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::a92f:a3c8:1f6b:6322/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: ::cc28:f3c5:70b1:420f/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:61536 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:55328319 (55.3 MB)  TX bytes:5679616 (5.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:536533 (536.5 KB)  TX bytes:536533 (536.5 KB)
```

Comment: Is it a usb or pci device?

Comment: It is a Realtek rtl8821a USB dongle.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of generic questions.

Answer (score 4):

With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
cd rtl8812AU
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

You have compiled the driver for your current running kernel only. When Update Manager installs a later one, also known as linux-image, re-compile:

```
cd  rtl8812AU
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Comment: Are you sure it will work? The original Realtek source shows that it is 8821, not 8812.

Comment: @Pilot6  Pretty sure. Please see post #53 here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339960&page=6 It is the exact same 0bda:0811 device.

Comment: @chili555 if it **IS** an 8812au, it's best to use **rtl8812au-dkms** from the repositories... however, I just grep'd my 8812au driver, and 0bda:0811 didn't show up, so maybe it is a 8821. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema The dkms won't build in most recent kernels. There is an AU post about the fix but I can't get it to work on my 4.8.0-xx kernel. I know the git version compiles (albeit with warnings) and covers the 0811 device.

Comment: @chili555 I had sent you some info about how to fix the rtl8812au-dkms driver. It involves changing the MAKE command in dkms.conf. It's working for me with the latest in 16.04.1, but I can't speak to the 4.8.0 kernel. Cheers, Al

Comment: @heynnema  But it doesn't cover the 0bda:0811 device? ?

Comment: @chili555 no 0811, but it does have usb:v0BDAp8812d. Maybe somebody added it to your git driver. And also, see <http://askubuntu.com/questions/832329/wifi-module-8812au-not-working-with-kernel-version-4-4-0-28-generic/832372#832372> for the info about the dkms fix. Cheers, Al

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46929/discussion-between-chili555-and-heynnema).

Comment: sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU.git
cd rtl8812AU
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au

that did not work for me still can not bring up my wifi I tried grep but that did not work either I am not sure what to do been looking all over for a solution.....

modinfo 8812au | grep 0811
sudo iwlist scan
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: Please confirm the result of this command: `modinfo 8812au | grep 0811` and also: `dkms status` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used synaptic and searched for rtl8812au-dkms . It worked perfectly once I unplugged and re-plugged the usb adapter. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[@chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/838368/821656) didn't work for me. After spending a couple of hours researching, I got this to work by downloading the Realtek RTL8812AU drivers from wikidevi.com. I'm unclear whether compiling/installing the Linux drivers first is needed (it compiles the networking drivers). The full set of steps:

- If you read [this issue](https://github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU/issues/100) on the GitHub repository he linked, it points to [this clone repository](https://github.com/gordboy/rtl8812au). Go there.
- Follow the build instructions from `README.md`. I used `dkpg`, if it matters.
- Type `lsusb`. You should see something like: `Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.`
- Note down the code `(0bda:0811)`, this is a unique identifier of your device.
- Go to [this page of RealTek drivers](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Realtek) and search for `RTL8811AU`. It'll link you to [this page](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Special:Ask?title=Special%3AAsk&q=%5B%5BChip1+model::RTL8811AU%5D%5D&po=%3FInterface%0D%0A%3FForm+factor=FF%0D%0A%3FInterface+connector+type=USB+conn.%0D%0A%3FFCC+ID%0D%0A%3FManuf%0D%0A%3FManuf+product+model=Manuf.+mdl%0D%0A%3FVendor+ID%0D%0A%3FDevice+ID%0D%0A%3FChip1+model%0D%0A%3FSupported+802dot11+protocols=PHY+modes%0D%0A%3FMIMO+config%0D%0A%3FOUI%0D%0A%3FEstimated+year+of+release=Est.+year&eq=yes&p%5Bformat%5D=broadtable&order%5B0%5D=ASC&sort_num=&order_num=ASC&p%5Blimit%5D=500&p%5Boffset%5D=&p%5Blink%5D=all&p%5Bsort%5D=&p%5Bheaders%5D=show&p%5Bmainlabel%5D=&p%5Bintro%5D=&p%5Boutro%5D=&p%5Bsearchlabel%5D=%E2%80%A6+further+results&p%5Bdefault%5D=&p%5Bclass%5D=sortable+wikitable+smwtable).
- Search for `0bda` and look for entries with `0811` in the next column. You'll find two (as of writing). Click either of them.
- On the right side, look for a link similar to `Driver version 5.3.4 available on Edimax site`. Click it to download the source of the driver.
- Unzip, untar, etc. and go into the directory in a command-prompt.
- Run `make`, and then `sudo make install`
- Unplug and plug in your device.
- The LED should flash, indicating it's on. Verify in Network Manager.
- Profit