# Help installing 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek

I was running my OS off a USB stick fine and the wifi was working. I installed it to my SSD and setup again but not the WIFI adaptor isn't working.

I followed the first time [Having problems seeing my wifi Ubuntu Gnome 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838131/having-problems-seeing-my-wifi-ubuntu-gnome-16-04) and it worked but since installing onto the SSD and doing the same its not working.

```
No wlan0 interface found
Please check drivers, try lsusb to check USB device is present
root@goldminer:~# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On the working device

```
root@coalminer:~# dkms status
amdgpu, 18.10-572953, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed
amdgpu, 18.10-572953, 4.4.0-127-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.59, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.59, 4.4.0-127-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 4.4.0-127-generic, x86_64: installed
```

On the SSD

```
root@goldminer:~# dkms status
amdgpu, 18.10-572953, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed
amdgpu, 18.10-572953, 4.4.0-127-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.59, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.59, 4.4.0-127-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.2.2, 4.13.16-hiveos, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg: added
rtl8812au, 5.2.9: added
```

Any advise? I think from trying to fix it ive been making it worse.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved.

I wiped the SSD and put the image on again.

Then straight away did

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Rebooted and its working.

Comment: Thank you. It worked like charm. Do I guess well that it need to be done every kernel update? It seems so

Comment: DKMS is for auto-updating. Should be working fine.

Comment: It worked like a charm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Use https://askubuntu.com/a/1165787/19938 for 5.x kernel

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS kernel 5.3.0-46-generic #38. But I found that WiFi 5/5.8 GHz performance was almost unusable. WiFi 2.4 GHz performance was fine. I'm going to try the 5.x kernel driver mentioned above.

Comment: @AlekseyDeryagin That 5.x driver repository has been removed :-(

Comment: Worked for me on Xubuntu 20.04.  Gave me a horrible interface name, but I can live with it.