# Unable to set up wireless adapter wf2180 on ubuntu 20.04lts

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I have usb dongle Netis wf2180 (Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter)

Neither automatically installed driver nor manually(manufacturer provided and dkms) works propertly. System doesn't recognize device as wlan adapter. Maybe someone knows solution?

Comment: This `rtl8811au` you can search for solutions.

Comment: I've tried few solutions and get no success.

Comment: Did you try this one? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045646/help-installing-0bda0811-realtek-semiconductor-corp It is the same device. If you did try it, tell us what went wrong: `sudo dkms status` and also: `sudo modprobe 8812au && dmesg | grep -i rtl`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This works pretty good. Thank you!