# Realtek 0bda:a811 WiFi Driver rtl8812AU on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, realtek-wireless

Fairly new linux user here, so be gentle. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 last stable release. Unfortunately, my PC is not near my internet access point, so I have to rely on wifi. I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035069/visible-0bdaa811-realtek-wifi-adapter-and-i-believe-installed-device-driver-n) that references [this driver](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux). Before doing their solution, I wanted to try the officially supported rtl8812au driver first, so I downloaded it from [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/rtl8812au-dkms) onto a USB from another computer and transferred it to my Ubuntu home folder. I was able to put all necessary dev packages from my install USB into my home folder and run `dpkg --install *.deb` to install the rtl8812au driver version 4.3.8 and all of its dependencies. I rebooted, but my system still couldn't see my wifi adapter.

I moved forward with the aforementioned stack exchange solution. Upon running those commands, I got this:
[here's a picture--sorry I couldn't copy and paste the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEggl.jpg)
There appears to be an issue with the definition of the `platform_wifi_power` functions?

After running `dkms status`, it shows the new version rtl8812au 4.3.14 has been added, but not installed. I'm stuck here, and I appreciate your help!

EDIT:
I was able to tether to my phone through usb with no fuss at all. I just turned on my personal hotspot and plugged it into usb, booted up, and I was online. This allowed me to run software update and apt update, apt install proper Nvidia drivers, and apt install rtl8812au-dkms. After reboot, my Nvidia drivers are working great now, but I still can’t connect to WiFi.

Edit 2:
I tried the proposed solution while tethered to my iPhone so I could do `git clone`, and I am now connected to wifi! I still don't understand what happened. Literally the only difference was downloading the repo with git clone rather than transferring via USB. Maybe some of the software updates I was able to run while tethered made the difference. Moral of the story for anyone out there: Personal hotspot is your friend!

Edit 3:
For clarity, I want to add that if you try to apt install rtl8812au-dkms first, like I did, you’ll have to remove it with `sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms` before you implement the solution below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**kernel >= 4.15.0-34**

Run these commands to install a working driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install
sudo dkms status
```

The output of the last line should now include:

```
rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
```

reboot

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I did exactly these steps, and I got the error on the `sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install` step and linked to the errors I encountered in the OP. And to clarify to anyone else trying this, you obviously have to `git clone` on a different computer that has internet access and then transfer than folder with USB.

Comment: See my second edit! I got it working! If I have troubles on future kernel updates, I'll have to keep this in mind. Please tell me this won't break on every kernel update...

Comment: It won't break. I experienced several kernel updates.

Comment: I get an error on the make command:
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.3.14 not found