# Wifi adapter not found On HP(linux 18.04)

Tags: gnome

I have HP Pavillion which has wifi Chipset of RTL8822BE .
Wireless network works perfectly on Windows 10 but show adpater not found in wireless network i tried every solution but dosen't work.Many of my mates are facing such issue on HP laptops please fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 18.10, I had an issue with a chip-set on my tablet (bluetooth and wifi); upgraded to a newer Kernel fixed the issues. You might want to try Ukuu...it is low risk, still at your own risk, b/c if the new kernel does not work or causes an issue, likely, using Grub menu, revert back to the previous kernel...a newer kernel might fix the issue.
I would perform all regular OS updates then use Ukuu.
So far, using Kernel 5.0, on my own laptop and tablet, do not have an issue but, experience varies. 
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/ukuu-easy-way-to-install-mainline-kernel-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can try the answer on https://askubuntu.com/a/1076824/712349.
If that does not work try to find a driver for RTL8822BE on github.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git`

`cd rtw88/ && make && sudo make install`

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de`

`sudo modprobe rtl8723de`

If all this doesn't work then remove and blacklist the previous driver using the commands given below and then restart -

`sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo sed -i '/blacklist bcma/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

`sudo sed -i '/blacklist brcmsmac/ d' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`