# Driver for USB WiFi dongle Realtek RTL8811AU chipset and Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 20.04

I'm running Ubuntu Server 20.04 on an ODROID H2+. I purchased an WiFi USB dongle based on the Realtek RTL8811AU chipset..

I cannot get it to work. I've tried three different drivers:

1. The driver here: https://wiki.odroid.com/odroid-h2/application_note/howto_wifi_driver_rtl8812au
2. The driver here: [Realtek 0bda:a811 WiFi Driver rtl8812AU on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076771/realtek-0bdaa811-wifi-driver-rtl8812au-on-ubuntu-18-04)
3. The driver by this: `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms`

At one point early on I got it to show up in `ip a` as enx200db03fa15e but even that is gone now.

I attach the output of the following commands:

```
lsusb
uname -a
lsmod | grep 8812
modinfo rtl8812au
mokutil --sb-state
sudo dkms status
journalctl -b | grep 8812
journalctl -b | grep supplicant
```

```
plum@odroid:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:3012 Dell Computer Corp. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05d5:0624 Super Gate Technology Co., Ltd USB2.1 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ uname -a
Linux odroid 5.4.0-48-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 10 10:58:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ lsmod | grep 8812
rtl8812au            1347584  0
cfg80211              704512  1 rtl8812au
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ modinfo rtl8812au
filename:       /lib/modules/5.4.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8812au.ko
version:        v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
author:         Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
description:    Realtek Wireless Lan Driver
license:        GPL
srcversion:     563D0DCC21D421BB16893BF
alias:          usb:v2357p011Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v3823p6249d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep400Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v056Ep4007d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p029Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p025Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0242d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0023d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3318d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3314d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0953d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA813d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0823d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0820d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFiscFFipFFin*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp0811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp9097d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0122d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0115d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p010Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2357p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p805Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3316d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3315d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB30d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0100d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1058p0632d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3426d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17D2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0409p0408d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0952d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2604p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p330Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1109d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1106d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp881Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8812d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
name:           rtl8812au
vermagic:       5.4.0-48-generic SMP mod_unload
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         odroid Secure Boot Module Signature key
sig_key:        64:9F:85:82:2B:66:F7:D6:82:0C:3D:59:F7:65:DF:6D:95:00:FE:B0
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      62:15:BE:12:E1:41:0F:65:31:57:C2:6D:C0:F1:81:C6:31:A0:10:F7:
                B6:75:16:26:97:E7:1F:58:58:85:89:1D:25:33:0C:DA:83:11:71:37:
                57:79:0D:80:FD:DD:F4:ED:CF:47:2F:9A:75:C3:DA:69:5B:19:A3:34:
                6C:94:BB:B8:34:B7:18:CD:31:CB:48:8B:CF:7A:00:A5:AF:8D:EE:5C:
                3D:79:8A:21:FD:D0:19:A2:79:63:EA:88:F2:BC:D7:B6:60:44:E9:68:
                C8:8E:BB:EC:10:8D:98:CC:A6:C9:B2:43:28:3A:56:33:A1:79:A4:0C:
                BA:20:09:FB:F9:89:D9:AD:F3:7B:14:A0:14:D9:E0:FD:07:1C:6B:E5:
                2E:62:B7:19:45:55:C9:44:42:C4:7E:1B:7F:D5:DC:94:32:A4:B0:8E:
                BA:C3:74:AB:57:9E:7A:85:6D:44:0C:33:BE:68:E6:F9:4A:98:F0:FD:
                FB:E4:5F:96:18:2A:A1:E1:63:EC:19:22:C0:4C:3B:28:2C:47:B0:D9:
                D0:BB:CF:C1:51:BA:11:EA:F9:51:A6:9C:91:90:11:A6:E1:A6:E5:3B:
                1C:EA:00:94:49:31:31:92:FF:92:3D:96:BA:34:60:A6:67:B6:71:FC:
                6A:DB:32:EB:0F:17:70:89:92:BD:99:6E:0D:79:09:14
parm:           rtw_ips_mode:The default IPS mode (int)
parm:           rtw_usb_rxagg_mode:int
parm:           rtw_qos_opt_enable:int
parm:           ifname:The default name to allocate for first interface (charp)
parm:           if2name:The default name to allocate for second interface (charp)
parm:           rtw_initmac:charp
parm:           rtw_channel_plan:int
parm:           rtw_special_rf_path:int
parm:           rtw_chip_version:int
parm:           rtw_rfintfs:int
parm:           rtw_lbkmode:int
parm:           rtw_network_mode:int
parm:           rtw_channel:int
parm:           rtw_mp_mode:int
parm:           rtw_wmm_enable:int
parm:           rtw_vrtl_carrier_sense:int
parm:           rtw_vcs_type:int
parm:           rtw_busy_thresh:int
parm:           rtw_ht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_bw_mode:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_enable:int
parm:           rtw_rx_stbc:int
parm:           rtw_ampdu_amsdu:int
parm:           rtw_vht_enable:int
parm:           rtw_lowrate_two_xmit:int
parm:           rtw_rf_config:int
parm:           rtw_power_mgnt:int
parm:           rtw_smart_ps:int
parm:           rtw_low_power:int
parm:           rtw_wifi_spec:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_cfg:int
parm:           rtw_antdiv_type:int
parm:           rtw_enusbss:int
parm:           rtw_hwpdn_mode:int
parm:           rtw_hwpwrp_detect:int
parm:           rtw_hw_wps_pbc:int
parm:           rtw_max_roaming_times:The max roaming times to try (uint)
parm:           rtw_mc2u_disable:int
parm:           rtw_80211d:Enable 802.11d mechanism (int)
parm:           rtw_notch_filter:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2:Enable only for P2P (uint)
parm:           rtw_led_enable:Enable status LED (int)
parm:           rtw_hiq_filter:0:allow all, 1:allow special, 2:deny all (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_en:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_mode:0:normal, 1:carrier sense (uint)
parm:           rtw_adaptivity_dml:0:disable, 1:enable (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_2g:BIT3:2G ext-PA, BIT4:2G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_amplifier_type_5g:BIT6:5G ext-PA, BIT7:5G ext-LNA (uint)
parm:           rtw_RFE_type:default init value:64 (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_2G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_TxBBSwing_5G:default init value:0xFF (uint)
parm:           rtw_OffEfuseMask:default open Efuse Mask vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_FileMaskEfuse:default drv Mask Efuse vaule:0 (uint)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_lmt_enable:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_tx_pwr_by_rate:0:Disable, 1:Enable, 2: Depend on efuse (int)
parm:           rtw_phy_file_path:The path of phy parameter (charp)
parm:           rtw_load_phy_file:PHY File Bit Map (int)
parm:           rtw_decrypt_phy_file:Enable Decrypt PHY File (int)
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for plum:
realtek-r8125, 9.003.05, 5.4.0-47-generic, x86_64: installed
realtek-r8125, 9.003.05, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.14, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: built
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ journalctl -b | grep 8812
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel: RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel: RTL871X: rtl8812au BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20150128-51
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel: Modules linked in: rapl rtl8812au(OE+) snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core intel_cstate snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio cfg80211 snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg joydev snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm snd_timer snd r8125(OE+) ucsi_acpi mei_me typec_ucsi soundcore mei typec mac_hid sch_fq_codel emc2103 coretemp ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs zstd_compress raid10 raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c raid1 raid0 multipath linear hid_generic usbhid hid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel i915 crypto_simd sdhci_pci i2c_algo_bit nvme cqhci drm_kms_helper cryptd glue_helper sdhci nvme_core i2c_i801 syscopyarea sysfillrect r8169
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  ? _rtw_malloc+0x2d/0x2f [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  ? _rtw_memcpy+0x10/0x12 [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  ? rtw_5g_rates_init+0x1a/0x1c [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  ? rtw_spt_band_alloc+0xb0/0xb2 [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  rtw_wdev_alloc+0x107/0x2ad [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  rtw_usb_if1_init+0x138/0x205 [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  rtw_drv_init+0x23a/0x2c5 [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel:  rtw_drv_entry+0x86/0x1000 [rtl8812au]
Oct 01 14:08:13 odroid kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$ journalctl -b | grep supplicant
Oct 01 14:09:42 odroid systemd[1]: Dependency failed for WPA supplicant for netplan enx200db03fa15e.
Oct 01 14:10:17 odroid systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Oct 01 14:10:17 odroid wpa_supplicant[752]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Oct 01 14:10:17 odroid systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
plum@odroid:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! This driver works beautifully. It's version 5.6.4.2, one generation newer than the drivers mentioned in the original post.

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au