# All the sudden, RTL8812AU wifi USB adapter stop working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, 18.04

I have a Realtek 8812AU WIFI USB adapter,and till yesterday, it was working fine on Ubuntu 18.04. But, today, all the sudden, Ubuntu stopped recognizing the adapter. I am not familiar with Linux or hardware stuff...
But, I am still writing the symptom as much as I can describe.

1. When I installed a driver for it a month ago, I used a command, `apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms`, and it was recognized with no trouble.
2. Today, Ubuntu suddenly stopped enabling the adapter. Wifi adapter list is empty on Setting menu. My Ubuntu is running on a dual boot machine. So, I restarted with Windows10, and the adapter has no issues working. So, I believe the adapter is fine physically.
3. I typed the  `apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms` command again. Ubuntu replied that the newest version is installed. So, the driver is still on Ubuntu.
4. I researched online and found the  `lsusb` command. By typing it, I found the adapter's company name was on a result from the command. So, at least, Ubuntu recognizes the adapter at the USB socket. I also switched it to another USB socket, and run the command. Then, it also showed the adapter on the different port.
5. There is a small issue with the machine; the Ubuntu machine currently doesn't have any access to a wired LAN connection. So, if you know a solution, please teach me where I can download a driver or some other required files from to the other machine, and what commands I need to type after I copy those files to the Ubuntu machine physically...
6. After I got a request from @Jeremy31 and @abu_bua (thanks for your quick reply!), I typed `dmesg | grep 8812au` and I received the following message from Ubuntu:

   `[  19.514781] 8812au: version magic '4.15.0-34-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.15.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload '`

Comment: Can you edit the post to include results for `dmesg | grep 8812au`

Comment: Thanks for correcting and formatting my comment!
I typed the command on Ubuntu as you instruct. I don't know why Ubuntu replied this message because  I didn't touch its kernel or driver at all after I confirmed the WIFI adapter was working...

Comment: Reboot and use grub menu/advanced options to boot into 4.15.0-34 so we can get you a real fix

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because of your comment, I could find a solution. It was a thread on this site from the last year, and I found that you had helped him to solve the same issues as I got this time. It was quite surprise. You are so wonderful :)

Answer (score 0):

After @Jeremy31 had given me an advice, I found this trouble was caused by the kernel update. So, I researched around. Then, I found the thread talking about the same issue last year. I was surprised that @Jeremy31 helped this person back then, too.

[WiFi module 8812AU not working with kernel version >= 4.4.0-28-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832329/wifi-module-8812au-not-working-with-kernel-version-4-4-0-28-generic)

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You could have up voted my answer on the other question and flagged this question as a duplicate

Comment: The page cannot let me vote yet.  I still have less than 15 reputations. The page says that I am still too new to up vote your answer on the thread. But, I have set duplicate flag. Thanks for your instruction again :)